# Filter specific values in terraform list

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-gcp, terraform0.12+

I've got a block of terraform code that produces a list of gcp regions

```
data "google_compute_regions" "available" {
  project = var.project
}

output "name" {
  value = data.google_compute_regions.available.names
}
```

```
  ~ name = [
      + "asia-east1",
      + "asia-east2",
      + "asia-northeast1",
      + "asia-northeast2",
      + "asia-northeast3",
      + "asia-south1",
      + "asia-southeast1",
      + "asia-southeast2",
      + "australia-southeast1",
      + "europe-north1",
      + "europe-west1",
      + "europe-west2",
      + "europe-west3",
      + "europe-west4",
      + "europe-west6",
      + "northamerica-northeast1",
      + "southamerica-east1",
      + "us-central1",
      + "us-east1",
      + "us-east4",
      + "us-west1",
      + "us-west2",
      + "us-west3",
      + "us-west4",
    ]
```

However, I want to filter out only the regions in europe.

Doing this

```
output "names" {
  value = [for s in data.google_compute_regions.available.names : s if s == "europe-west1"]
}
```

only gives me one region, which is not what I want.

```
+ names = [
    + "europe-west1",
  ]
```

I'm not sure if wildcards are supported or how to write the logic for it.

I've tried using filers as described [here](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/oci/latest/docs/guides/filters) but I don't seem to be getting it right.

```
data "google_compute_regions" "available" {
  project = var.project

  filter {
    name   = "name"
    values = ["europe-*"]
  }
}
```

But I run into the error
`Blocks of type "filter" are not expected here.`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Since it looks like filter is not supported on that data source for some reason, you will need to do a regex in the output, like this:

```
output "names" {
  value = [for s in data.google_compute_regions.available.names : s if length(regexall("europe.*", s)) > 0]
}
```

Comment: You're right Mark. 

I've updated the question with what I was doing with filters which is quite similar to your example actually. And my error message.

Comment: Now I get the error `Unsuitable value for left operand: number required` I wonder if its due to `s` being a list.

Comment: @Hammed sorry, I left a closing parenthesis out. Check my updated answer.

Comment: This works. Thanks a lot, Mark. I've definitely learned something new today.